# Undefined reference to Boost Thread

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, ubuntu, boost

I am trying to compile and use the Boost 1.54 libraries and have run into a deadend.

I compiled and installed the libraries like mentioned in the documentation:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 install
```

I even tried a complete reinstall using:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 threading=multi install
```

I have linked using `-lboost_thread` and `-L*path` to boost*/bin.v2/libs

I am still getting the following linker errors:

```
undefined reference to boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()
undefined reference to boost::thread::join_noexcept()
```

I am using gcc 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 in Eclipse.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What about `-lboost_system`?

Comment: It is also linked, since i am also using asio.

Comment: Can you show your actual linker invocation?

Comment: Here it is: Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/bin.v2/libs -o "test"  ./src/main.o   -lboost_system -lboost_thread-mt
./src/main.o: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:180: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
./src/main.o: In function `boost::thread::join()':
/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:756: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1

Comment: Hm... you don't actually have `boost_thread` in there, only `boost_thread-mt`. Could that matter?

Comment: This is was just an experiment from one of the answers here.Same error with -lboost-thread:
g++ -L/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/bin.v2/libs -o "test"  ./src/main.o   -lboost_system -lboost_thread
./src/main.o: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:180: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
./src/main.o: In function `boost::thread::join()':
/usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:756: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1

Answer (score 5):

After quite a bit of pain with the default boost on ubuntu repositories, I installed boost 1.54.0 (from the official webpage) with the default options, and the following worked for me:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -L/usr/local/lib/ -lboost_thread
```

P.S: On Ubuntu 12.04, **gcc 4.63**.

P.S2: Included in my `test.cpp` are:

```
#include "boost/thread/thread.hpp"
#include  "boost/bind.hpp"
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393211) for the solution when using CMake.