# CMake MinGW fails to link boost

Tags: boost, cmake, g++, mingw, fedora

I've been struggling to understand why CMake does not compile my program anymore. I made a container for cross-compile a C++ program for Windows. The environment:

- Fedora 31
- `cmake` 3.17.4
- `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` 9.2.1
- `boost` 1.69

The following code is my current `cmake` toolchain file for `mingw`:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PFX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE -x64)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PFX}/sys-root/mingw/include)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PFX}/sys-root/mingw/lib)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost 1.69 REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PFX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PFX}-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PFX})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

The building process interrupts when linking the executable. It produces:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_log-mt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
```

What shocks me the most is that it used to build (no changes have been made to the environment) and `boost` is installed from RPM. Funny things is that if I omit `-lboost_thread-mt`, off course, it complains.

Comment: So, the linker says that it cannot find a library `boost_thread-mt`. Where this library is located on your system? You set `Boost_DEBUG`. Have you checked its output about location of libraries? There are also strange things about toolchain: 1. `find_package` is rarely called in the toolchain file, it should be called from `CMakeLists.txt`. 2. Directory `/usr/local/include` refers to the **host** system include directory. Using it for cross-compilation is usually wrong. The same is about `/usr/local/lib`. 3. Option `-L` is not a **compiler** flag, so shouldn't be added to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: You're cross-building for Windows using MinGW-w64. On the other hand you say boost is installed via RPM. Are you sure you have Boost installed for Windows/MinGW-w64, and the RPM installed version is not just for your Linux platform?

Comment: Hey thanks. Off course the `Boost_DEBUG` is there for a reason. Boost is correctly installed and it's root is where i specify `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` since CMake alone isn't able to find it. The use of `/usr/local/include` might be wrong but the host is a Docker container which serves only as a building environment and I put some locally built deps there. Regarding tour second observation, it's true, but my `CMakeLists` is pretty long and messy and it's easier to operate on the toolchain. Plus when I build for Linux I do not have problems.

Comment: @BrechtSanders off course boost is installed for `MinGW`, yes

Comment: The call `find_package(Boost)` which you show doesn't have a COMPONENTS specification, so `boost_thread-mt` is not what is produced by this call. Nor this call adds link directories for Boost libraries. So, where `boost_thread-mt` is specified in your `CMakeLists.txt`? Are you sure that you correctly add link directories for Boost libraries? The preferred way for work with Boost `thread` library is specifying it as COMPONENTS: `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread REQUIRED)`, see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398161/3440745) as example.

Comment: `boost_thread-mt` is exactly located where I expect it to be. The path is `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib`, also the debug value of `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE`  is as follows: `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`. To me it looks like I would expect it to be. I am not an expert but I would say this thing is configured in the right way. In fact it is, as I am writing I realized that the library has "-x64" appended. But isn't `set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE -x64)` used to avoid having to link aganinst `boost_thread-mt-x64`?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting many variables that should be correctly set by `find_package()` such as `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR`.

Also, you don't specify any components with find_package, as would be the standard way, unless you just want to use the header-only part of boost.

Thus, you are using find_package boost in unsupported/unspecified ways which might have worked in the past, by chance, but broke later.

What definitely works on Fedora 36 is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0...3.22.1)
project(some_project CXX)

# work-around: FindBoost: Boost_ARCHITECTURE not detected on MinGW
# https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20587
if(MINGW)
    if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
        set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE "-x64")
    else()
        set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE "-x32")
    endif()
endif()

# works with/without
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

# set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

find_package(Boost 1.54
    REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    system
    filesystem) # just an example, add what you need

add_executable(somebinary main.cc sometranslationunit.cc)
target_link_libraries(somebinary ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Build with:

```
mkdir build-cross
cd build-cross
mingw64-cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. # or whatever build type
mingw64-make somebinary
```