# Undefined reference to boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost

So i was just messing around boost.asio. They have a pretty nice tutorial page, where i [just followed the instructions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html) and pretty much copied the code. Previous examples are working just fine, but when it comes to threads i get bunch of errors

```
FAILED: untitled 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -lboost_system -g  CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o -o untitled   && :
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: warning: relocation against `_ZTVN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseE' in read-only section `.text._ZN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseC2Ev[_ZN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseC5Ev]'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':
/home/user_me/Sys_Builds/boost_1_79_0/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:162: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
/home/user_me/Sys_Builds/boost_1_79_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:182: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `boost::thread::~thread()':
.
.
.
```

I use the boost 1-79-0. I downloaded binaries from official website and run basically two commands inside of the directory

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 install
```

After this i just added the line

```
 include_directories("/home/user_me/Sys_Builds/boost_1_79_0")
```

to cmake (i use clion as IDE). As said before, it seems like everything is working just fine but threads (which is pretty weird).
<del>In case you're just waiting to markup this post as duplicate - i've came across 4 or 5 similarish posts on varius sites and nothing has worked for me.</del>

#### Solution

As you can read in the comments i was including only header files hence problem with linking the library. Using the link (to post where i should've found the solution before making another) provided #btdrescherjm i rewrote the CMakeLists.txt to

```
#Project details
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(untitled)

#Setting cmake standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

#Boost config section
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread REQUIRED)

#Adding exec
add_executable(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        Boost::thread
)
```

Comment: `include_directories("/home/user_me/Sys_Builds/boost_1_79_0")` is not correct. You should use find_package() and target_link_libraries()

Comment: Just setting the include directory will work with header only libraries in boost but not libraries that need to be linked.

Comment: How should i use target_link libraries()? I've tried find_package tho "find_package(Boost 1.79.0 COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)" or "find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)" is what i tried

Comment: Your CMakeLists.txt should look like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398161/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398161/487892)

Comment: Thank you all so much it works just fine now. I'm just too much of an idiot and didn't even notice this is linking error.

Comment: Use the package configuration script that comes with the boost installation: `set(Boost_DIR "/path/too/boost/install/root") find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread CONFIG) target_link_libraries(... PRIVATE Boost::thread)` Setting `Boost_DIR` is only required for non-default install locations